# PHP: Should I use MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS and MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL flags at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I'm creating a SSL connection with PHP to a MySQL server and want to minimize the size of the data transfer.

I am wondering if I need to use both the MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS and MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL flags?

Or does the SSL flag have built-in compression?

Comment: SSL doesn't minimize anything, it's a security concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [SSL protocol](http://imysql.com/mysql-internal-manual/ssl.html) says (highlighting is mine):

> The MySQL Protocol also supports encryption and authentication via SSL. The encryption is transparent to the rest of the protocol and is **applied after the data is compressed** right before the data is written to the network layer.

This means that SSL encryption will not compress the mysql data stream on its own.